# MySQL create custom error logfile in Apache Root

Tags: mysql, error-logging

The title of this question placed in superuser's *search* box returned  "0 Results"

What.  Everybody in the world but me knows how to do that?   :)

From the reading I did for the last hour and a half, I figured that this would create
an error log file and so as an experiment, I entered this via the Windows command prompt
shell... then created an intentional error starting up a script on my localhost.
The Website, as expected, failed to load and I got the correct mysql error appearing on
screen, but then when I checked down in MySQL folder/subfolders, there had not been a
new error log file created.

Suggestions?  What to research?

Comment: how did you install mysql on windows, was it WAMP, XAMP, or full MySQL server install?

Comment: Full MySQL server.  I got the issues sorted eventually, using Workbench to revise my.ini and specifically change the settings and create new files in the directory Apache accesses; now I have the queries and all easily available, saves lots of time when I am working to just have a simple html page grab the current content of the new MySQL error and general query logs, and view them.